# want to display content in materialize tabs with mysql and php js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, cordova

I am developing simple Cordova application with some MySQL database retrieve data with help of jquery.
I want to display database content in tabs.
This is my HTML code

```
<ul id="tabs-swipe-demo" class="tabs">
  </ul>
<div id="tabs"></div>
```

this is my JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('ul.tabs').tabs({
  swipeable : true
});

var url_string = document.URL;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var unit = url.searchParams.get("unit");
var subject = url.searchParams.get("subject");
$("#logo-container").text(unit);
var ans;
var url="http://api.tectiqcompany.com/units.php?table="+subject;
$.getJSON(url,function(result){
   console.log(result);
  $.each(result, function(i, field){
    var que = field.COL2;
    var a = field.COL3;
    var b = field.COL4;
    var c = field.COL4;
    var d = field.COL6;
    ans = field.COL7;
    var desc = field.COL8;
    if(i == 0){
      $(".tabs").append('<li class="tab"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-'+(i+1)+'">'+(i+1)+'</a></li>');
    }else{
      $(".tabs").append('<li class="tab"><a href="#test-swipe-'+(i+1)+'">'+(i+1)+'</a></li>');
    }
    $("#tabs").append('<div id="test-swipe-'+(i+1)+'" class="col s12"><div style="padding: 15px;">'+(i+1)+'.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+que+'<p><input name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" /><label for="test1">'+a+'</label></p><p><input name="group1" type="radio" id="test2" /><label for="test2">'+b+'</label></p><p><input name="group1" type="radio" id="test3" /><label for="test3">'+c+'</label></p><p><input name="group1" type="radio" id="test4" /><label for="test4">'+d+'</label></p></div></div>');

  });

});

});
```

this is output:

OUTPUT SCREENSHOP

[image]

I am using Materializecss and JQuery latest Version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your swipeable tabs code after appending the html to tabs.

Take a look,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var url_string = document.URL;
    var url = new URL(url_string);
    var unit = url.searchParams.get("unit");
    var subject = url.searchParams.get("subject");
    $("#logo-container").text(unit);
    var ans;
    var url = "http://api.tectiqcompany.com/units.php?table=" + subject;
    $.getJSON(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        $.each(result, function(i, field) {
            var que = field.COL2;
            var a = field.COL3;
            var b = field.COL4;
            var c = field.COL4;
            var d = field.COL6;
            ans = field.COL7;
            var desc = field.COL8;
            if (i == 0) {
                $(".tabs").append('<li class="tab"><a class="active" href="#test-swipe-' + (i + 1) + '">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>');
            } else {
                $(".tabs").append('<li class="tab"><a href="#test-swipe-' + (i + 1) + '">' + (i + 1) + '</a></li>');
            }
            $("#tabs").append('<div id="test-swipe-' + (i + 1) + '" class="col s12"><div style="padding: 15px;">' + (i + 1) + '.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + que + '<p><input name="group1" type="radio" id="test1" /><label for="test1">' + a + '</label></p><p><input name="group1" type="radio" id="test2" /><label for="test2">' + b + '</label></p><p><input name="group1" type="radio" id="test3" /><label for="test3">' + c + '</label></p><p><input name="group1" type="radio" id="test4" /><label for="test4">' + d + '</label></p></div></div>');

        });

        $('ul.tabs').tabs({
            swipeable: true
        });

    });

});
```